# Apache mod_rewrite serves same content for different urls

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-cache

I have strange issue, I cant find the answer nowhere. I have set apache2 server with mod_disk_cache. I have strange issues where I get same page for different URL's. Let's say that I visit page via homepage - it works fine. If I go to the article, from the homepage, I can see the article - works fine. Back to the homepage - works fine. From the homepage to some other article - ISSUE: I still have content of the home page.

I'm my development server everything works well. On the production server I get those issues.

Some details:

DEV server:
Windows 7
apache 2.2.17
php: 5.3.4

PRODUCTION server:
centOS
apache 2.2.3
php: 5.2.9

HTTPD.CONF

```
...
ExpiresActive On

<Directory "/var/www/html/site-name">
  Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

  ExpiresDefault A86400

  <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif)">
    ExpiresDefault A31536000
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
    ExpiresDefault A31536000
  </FilesMatch>  

</Directory>

# Server Caching!
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
  <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
    CacheRoot /opt/cache-dir
    CacheEnable disk /
    CacheDirLevels 5
    CacheDirLength 3
  </IfModule>
</IfModule> 

# Server Compressing
#SetEnv gzip-only-text/html 1

<Location />
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</Location>

# Disable captcha caching! 
<Location "/index/captchaimage">
  Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store"
  Header Set Expires "Sun, 11 Dec 2011 00:18:40 GMT"
</Location>
```

MOD_REWRITE configuration

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|es\.|forum\.)?domain\.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ - [L]


RewriteRule ^sitemaps\.xml /index.php?get_sitemap=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemaps\.es\.xml /index.php?get_sitemap=1&lang=es [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemaps\.forum\.xml /index.php?get_sitemap=1&type=forum [NC,L]

#original 
RewriteRule ^sitemaps\.xml$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemaps\.es\.xml$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemaps\.forum\.xml$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^rssfeed\.xml$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|es|links|forum)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^.*/img/(articles|fancybox|users)?/?(.*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg|bmp)) public/img/$1/$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule uploader.php /public/uploader.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Well I hope that out there is someone who will be able to help or at least point me at some good docs. BTW: yes i read all the apache docs!

Regards!

Comment: I’m seeing the same problem with 2.4.33 almost 7 years later.